# Open new page when clicking on a custom react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I am doing this task, which is creating a PM System in React.

So main functionality is having a list of projects, which have to be acquired from a JSON file (It is made clear that I should not use a DB). So on the home page we have a list of projects and we should be able to click on any one of them and when clicked a new page should open. The new page will display the project with additional information - the tasks in the project and their status.

I assume I should do this with routing, but I have basic understanding of React, although I find it interesting. So how should I approach this, should I wrap my project component in a Link? Also when I open the new page how do I render the same component but with additional info?

Below you can find my code so far:

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Projects} from './components/Projects'
import {Header} from './Header.js'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Projects />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Project.js

```
import React from "react";

export const Project = ({name}) => {
    console.log(name)
    if (!name) return <div />;
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h5>{name}</h5>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };
```

Projects.js

```
import React from "react";
import data from "../data/data.json";
import {Project} from "./Project.js";


export const Projects = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="project-container">
        {data.map((data) => {
          console.log(data)
          return (
            <div key={data.Name}>
              <Project
                name={data.Name}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Check the library react-router and follow it's basic tutorial to implement SPA routing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make dynamic routes with react-router-dom.

Here you provide dynamically parameter "id";

Adding link to react-router-dom documentation - https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { DetailPage } from '../pages/DetailPage';

export const useRoutes = () => {

  return (
    <Routes>
       <Route path="/detail/:id" element={<DetailPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Then you create a Page component to display data about your chosen project.

```
import { Project } from '../components/Project';

export const DetailPage = () => {
  /* 
  You can get your ID param with react-router-dom hook - useParams();

  const { id } = useParams();

  Your custom logic for getting data for the project which you want 
  to show on this page and drop it into your Project component.

  */

  return <Project project={project} />;
};
```

In your case, you can fetch a list of your projects from DB, then render them as a list and provide everyone onClick with redirecting to the path with an id of the current project. After clicking, you will have such id and fetch data for a current project and render it then.
In your case, you can fetch a list of your projects from DB, then render them as a list and provide everyone onClick with redirecting to the path with an id of the current project. After clicking, you will have a project id in your route and fetch data for a current project and render it then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me where should I create the useRoutes() and why do we create it as a component? Also since when I open the detail page for projects and then i need to have a detail page for tasks, should I create a detailPageTask separately? Finally, "then render them as a list and provide everyone onClick with redirecting to the path with an id of the current project. After clicking, you will have such id and fetch data for a current project and render it then." I do not quite get this? I should provide onClick to my <Project> component? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Krblaze you make useRoutes as an independent component for describing your routes logic in your app and put it in your App.js file as a variable. We create it as a component because react-router provides us with their components for routes. Check documentation about react-router-dom. About third, I think you need to try it because it depends on your logic. And the last, you just need to make a component where you will render all your projects. In Array.map(), you will be able to add to every "div" for example onClick function, which will redirect to your details page with a unique id.